# How to list the categories by custom taxonomy created?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type named 'projects' with link custom taxonomy named 'projects'. I have added the five different project categories with this project taxonomy with two level of hierarchy [custom post type ui](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/installation/). I tried to find function to get these five categories with taxonomy name 'projects' but i did not get the solution. Can anyone help me out how to get the list of these categories created with taxonomy named 'projects'. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `get_terms`. The following code show you how to access the terms. Please see the [Codex page for get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) for more information about the args that you can send to the function. I also show all of the data that is returned in the array of objects.

```
// Set your args
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0   // Show terms that are not associated with any posts
);

// Get the terms
$projects = get_terms('projects', $args);

// Loop through and use terms
foreach($projects as $project)
{
    echo 'Term ID ' . $project->term_id;
    echo 'Name: ' . $project->name;
    echo 'Slug: ' . $project->slug;
    echo 'Term Group ' . $project->term_group;
    echo 'Term Taxonomy ID: ' . $project->term_taxonomy_id;
    echo 'Taxonomy: ' . $project->taxonomy;
    echo 'Description ' . $project->description;
    echo 'Parent: ' . $project->parent;
    echo 'Count: ' . $project->count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked .. Actually I tried this one too but did not work may be there was some problem with my code... Thanks again

Comment: The `hide_empty=0` can make or break you. Intuitively, most people expect this to automatically return all of the terms; however, by default it only gets terms that are associated with posts.